# Ubuntu upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 got stuck at crash signatures.k shut down ,how to resolve?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, 20.04, upgrade

I have dual boot of windows 7 with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and was upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS ,it got interrupted in between after that It shows that not all update will be there and gave option for partial upgrade but still I went for ,just continue and it started upgrading ,after the upgrade it said upgrade successful and asked for restart but since then its not booting up and getting stuck at the following statement showing :

`started WPA supplicant.cessful boot for GRUB.d.ally.nel crash signatures.k was shut down ....`

after that It doesn't do anything ,just stuck at this point .I don't know how to proceed and resolve it , should I try to resolve it through Ubuntu DVD or pen drive boot ,will it repair it then ? I'm sorry I'm still not a comfortable user of Ubuntu/Linux so need support from experienced users .

System config : Intel X64 , 12 GB RAM , 1 TB HD

Thank you !

UPDATE : Its a Desktop upgrade , its not a partial upgrade though It asked me during upgrade GUI option but I went for normal upgrade .I am a developer so I am using apps like android studio , intelliJ, Eclipse, VSCode etc .

Comment: Just to be clear: is that the literal error message you get every time you try to boot?

Comment: Your details aren't clear to me, firstly I don't know if you're asking about a Server or Desktop install (*that is a significant difference, especially with regards options*), and I'm unclear about your interruption & partial upgrade (*another item I consider significant*).  Given the unknowns, esp. if a desktop system, I'd perform a non-destructive re-install with a later release (20.04 & 22.04) but I don't know your system, what type of system (*I'd be less likely to use this option if you're using a Server install*), what 3rd party apps you use (*non-destructive is best with non-3rd party*)

Comment: FYI:  If you want the best community support; you should upgrade whilst we can look up package details for the release you're moving from (ie. *before EOL or EOSS*) as it's now too late & many of those details are either gone, or *outdated* (unless we have a system of that release handy, or ESM *enabled* systems thus can see those details)

Comment: @Jos I have shared the last line of the complete message ,the place where it exactly gets stuck every time .

Comment: @guiverc Its a Desktop installation ,  It was not a partial upgrade ,though It asked for it as an option but I didn't opted for it during my Upgrade .

Comment: @guiverc Is there any further info I should share ,I'm sorry but I'm still not much comfortable with Ubuntu in general . apology for that !